# Pass the derivative under integral

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose we have an operator $T: C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that it has a singular integral representation
\begin{equation*}
 Tf = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}K(x,y)f(y)dy
\end{equation*}
where $K(x,y)$ is singular when $y = x$ and and smooth when $y \neq x$. Moreover, assume that $K(x,y)$ is rapid decreasing when $\lvert x - y \rvert \to 0$. Can we pass the gradient of $Tf$ inside the integral, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
  \nabla Tf = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}K(x,y) \nabla f(y)dy
\end{equation*}
I don't know whether this is true or not. If it is true, I'd also like to see how one invokes Dominated Converence Theorem in this case. In reality, I'm trying to show this is true for a pseudo-differential operator of order 1 on a compact, boundaryless Riemannian manifold. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The differentiation is with respect to $x$, not $y$. The dependence of the integral expression on $x$ is in $K(x,y)$, not $f(y)$. If differentiation under the integral sign is justifiable, it will be a differentiation of $K(x,y)$ with respect to $x$, not $f(y)$ with respect to $y$.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point. But what if we add the condition that $\nabla_{x}K(x,y) = \nabla_{y}K(x,y)$? Will the formula then be justified by integration by parts (assume all boundary terms vanish)?